# How to get number of current week in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I develop an app that needs to get the current week. I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *dateString = @"1-1-2011";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"%d", comp.week);

    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

but it shows me 52. Which is actually a wrong result. Please, suggest me any ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about if the year starts on Saturday? This week isn't the first...it's the last of the previous year = 52nd week:).

Comment: @GrizzlyNetch: It's the 52nd of the previous year in the ISO-8601 numbering. It would be the first in the US numbering. Then there's the fact US weeks start with Sunday. And apparently there's a few other week numbering systems around just to make things more confusing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering  (Week numbers are probably the only thing that matches DST in terms of being frustrating to handle correctly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The week date depends on which numbering standard is in use. For instance, the ISO-8601 standard [defines week 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) of a year as "the week with the year's first Thursday in it".

The first of January 2011 was a Saturday, which means the following week was week 1 of 2011, making the week 27.12.2010–2.1.2011 week 52 of 2010.

Also, there's several incompatible standards for when weeks start or end and how weeks in a year are numbered. This makes week numbers a confusing way to specify a date range and the best solution to avoid using them.

From the documentation to NSCalendar, it seems you could also use  [`setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:) to adjust the way it numbers weeks.

Comment: I tried to change value of dateString to @"03-01-2011", but NSLog now says 1 week. Where exactly should I define setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek? Maybe I should somewhere define the current date?

Comment: "Minimum days in first week" should mean how many days from a given year must week 1 of said year include. I'm assuming that if you set it to 1, the first of January will be in week one even if it's a Sunday. You should call the setter method after you create the NSCalendar instance.

Comment: The third of January 2011 was a Monday – it would belong to week 1 of 2011 in any sane week numbering standard.

Comment: @Noobass: Just to be perfectly clear: saying that the week number for 1.1.2011 is "52" is **correct** (for given values of "correct"). Depending on your use case, you might not want to "fix" this behaviour – the week numbers your app shows should be consistent with what other calendars your users use show.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you very much. Now every things clear to me.